# Inputting Longitude and Latitude in CSV from Geotagged, Photo Coordinates (WGS 84)

Tags: qgis, csv, wgs84, photos, geotag

I am trying to take Geotagged picture coordinates and put them into a CSV file to display in QGIS as point values. Using Picasa, I can see that the picture coordinates are in the correct locations on the sample map. However, when I take the long and lat of the pictures and put it into a CSV file--formatted for QGIS--the points show up in incorrect locations. For example:

Latitude: **11 23\'49.9" N** displayed in the photo's properties --> put as **11.23499** in CSV file

Long: **122 3\'35.9"E** displayed in the photo's properties --> put as **122.3359** in CSV file

When I load it into QGIS as a layer, it shows up in a different, incorrect location. Also, I have checked my CRS to make sure it is correct. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you take into account that there are 60 minutes in one degree, and 60 seconds in each minute?

Comment: How are you obtaining the coordinates for the geotagged images? Are you writing down the numbers or have an automated process?

Comment: A more direct approach is to use Photo2Shape plugin. It directly takes the folder containing the geotagged images and creates a point shape file.